# Google analytics and slow load

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a bit new to this and a total non-techy. Basically the site I work on doesn't currently have much in the way of analytics other than the standard GA reporting and some events as and when reporting has been required by marketing. I come from a background where the site I worked on had a different analytics tool and pretty much every click event or interaction on the site could be reported on. This made it really easy to pull off analytics on any area of the site as and when required in a more proactive way without the need for dev work.

The developers I am working with now are telling me that if we were to put events on the core areas of the site I have asked for (ie core user journeys and key features), it will affect the load times of the pages too much. Could someone advise, 1- is this the case with GA? 2- is there any way around it? 3- is this an issue unique to GA or any analytics tool

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Google Analytics or any web analytics tool. Google code is loaded asynchronously (so it can't block page load) and by the time the events are attached the page is already loaded (else attaching events would hardly be possible).

It might be that your developers are concerned that page performance (not load time, though) suffers when they add a script that  has to modify every single DOM element. That argument might have merits (hard to say without knowing your site) but has nothing to do with the analytics tool.